# Solve equation: $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=1-x-x^2$

Tags: quadratics

$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=1-x-x^2$$
I am doing this problem for about an hour and I cant get to all the results. What is the easiest way to do this? I tried by squaring everything right away but at the I end I get a pretty messed up equation that is not easy to factor at all: $x(-x^3-2x^2+2x+3)=0$. Of course I see that one answer is $x=0$ but how do I get other answers?

Comment: Hint: Can you solve $\sqrt{1+u}=1-u$?

Comment: Cautionary note - when squaring an equation like this you may get extra solutions, so you always need to substitute back into the original equation. (This is because if you square $y=a$ to obtain $y^2=a^2$, the second equation is also satisfied by $y=-a$)

Comment: @RiktasMath Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Hint

$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=1-x-x^2$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=2-(1+x+x^2)$$
$$\sqrt{u}=2-u$$
Square it ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$x(-x^3-2x^2+2x+3)=-x(x+1)(x^2+x-3)$$

Comment: How was I supposed to see that?

Comment: By rational root theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem a root for $(-x^3-2x^2+2x+3)$ must be among 3,1,-1,-3

Comment: It must be one of those 4 numbers *if it's rational*, i.e., if the polynomial can be factored over the integers.

Comment: @Did Those as already G Tony Jacobs observed it must be if it is rational, and those are the values we can use to find a factorization that indeed works for x=-1.

Comment: Yeah. Hence, yet again a wrong comment.

Comment: Whatever the precise merits of the comment, using the rational root theorem to find an easy factor of a cubic (if it exists) is a try worth noting for OP.

Comment: @MarkBennet Of course. And overlooking that this criterion "misses" the non rational roots is seriously misleading the OP.

Comment: ((Yet again a factual comment addressing a mathematical error, which "conveniently" disappears.))

Answer (score 0):

For $x \ge 0$, note that $\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}$ gets bigger when $x$ increases while $1 - x - x^2$ get's smaller. Since an upward sloping line and a downward sloping line cross in only one place, the only solution is $x = 0$.

For $x \le -1$ the same reasoning shows $-1$ is the only solution, so it only remains to check in between $-1$ and $0$.

Since $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ is "curved upwards" (as $x^2$ has a positive coefficient), and $f(-1) = f(0) = 1$, we know $f(x)$ is less than $1$ in between $-1$ and $0$. Since $\sqrt f < 1 \iff f < 1$, it follows that $\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}$ < 1 when $-1 < x < 0$.

Since $g(x) = 1 - x - x^2$ is "curved downwards" and $g(-1) = g(0) = 1$, we have $1 - x - x^2 > 1$ when $-1<x<0$. So the only two solutions are $-1$ and $0$.